# Printing escape sequence character in python

Tags: python, ascii

I tried to print the escape sequence characters or the ASCII representation of numbers in Python in a `for` loop.

Like:

```
for i in range(100, 150):
    b = "\%d" %i
    print(b)
```

I expected the output like,

```
A
B
C
```

Or something.

But I got like,

```
\100
\101
```

How to print ASCII representation of the numbers?

Comment: Like others have said, you can do `chr(i)` to get the ASCII character represented by `i`, and that is the better way to do it. But you could also achieve it with percent-formatting, with `'%c' % i`. It's just good to know all your options.

Answer (score 2):

There's a builtin function for python called `ord` and `chr`

`ord` is used to get the value of ASCII letter, for example:

```
print(ord('h'))
```

The output of the above is 104

`ord` only support a one length string

`chr` is inverse of `ord`

```
print(chr(104))
```

The output of the above is `'h'`

`chr` only supports integer. float, string, and byte doesn't support

`chr` and `ord` are really important if you want to make a translation of a text file (encoded text file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to print the ASCII value of a character.

`print(ord('b'))`

`> 98`

Likewise, you can use the [`chr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to print the ASCII character represented by a number.

`print(chr(98))`

`> b`

Comment: Thank you sir but I want the reverse action of this function, sir

Comment: The reverse is `chr`.

Comment: @SivaPrasanaPandiyan.C see updated answer.

Comment: `chr` takes an `int` not a `str`, so you need to call `chr(98)` not `chr('98')`.

Comment: @nog642 oof, embarrassing mistake on my part - thanks for pointing it out.